# SQLite doesn't have KEYs?

Tags: database, sqlite

I see I can add PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE or FOREIGN KEY.

but no `KEY` like in MySQL ?

How do I get a column indexed?

Comment: [CREATE INDEX](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called `INDEX`, see [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html)

Comment: so how do I use that with CREATE TABLE? `myfield COLLATE myfieldindex ASC` ?

Comment: It seems you have to add the index with a separate `CREATE INDEX` statement instead of inside the `CREATE TABLE`.